# Query using spatial data slow, how to speed up

Tags: mysql, geospatial, spatial-query

I am trying to speed up a query using spatial data. (simplified query below)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM properties
    WHERE MBRCONTAINS(ST_MakeEnvelope(Point(33.497224314994114, -111.98568371835003),
             Point(33.43897750924284, -112.09826410537367)), pt);
```

Running Explain on this give me the following:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | properties |  | ALL |  |  |  |  | 260761 | 100 | Using where |

I did add a spatial index on 'pt' defined as a point

How can I speed up this query? This one takes around 15seconds and would like to reduce it to 1s

**EDIT**
The table holds the data for real estate listings. We build real estate applications. We implemented a map search and by pulling the bounding box from the Google Maps API we would like to show the listings within that bounding box matching certain criteria.

```
create table properties
(
    id bigint unsigned auto_increment
        primary key,
    City varchar(50) null,
    ListAgentMlsId varchar(25) null,
    ListOfficeMlsId varchar(25) null,
    ListOfficeName varchar(255) null,
    ListPrice int null,
    ListingId varchar(255) null,
    ModificationTimestamp varchar(27) null,
    PropertyType varchar(50) null,
    StandardStatus varchar(25) null,
    StatusChangeTimestamp varchar(27) null,
    MemberStatus varchar(25) null,
    MemberModificationTimestamp varchar(27) null,
    OfficeModificationTimestamp varchar(27) null,
    OfficeStatus varchar(25) null,
    MediaOrder int null,
    ResourceRecordID varchar(255) null,
    OpenHouseListingId varchar(255) null,
    OpenHouseModificationTimestamp varchar(27) null,
    AccessibilityFeatures text null,
    Appliances text null,
    ArchitecturalStyle text null,
    AssociationAmenities text null,
    AssociationFee int null,
    AssociationFeeFrequency varchar(25) null,
    AssociationFeeIncludes text null,
    AssociationYN tinyint(1) null,
    AttachedGarageYN tinyint(1) null,
    Basement text null,
    BathroomsFull int null,
    BathroomsHalf int null,
    BathroomsOneQuarter int null,
    BathroomsPartial int null,
    BathroomsThreeQuarter int null,
    BathroomsTotalInteger int null,
    BedroomsTotal int null,
    BodyType text null,
    BusinessType text null,
    CarportSpaces int null,
    CoListAgentFirstName varchar(50) null,
    CoListAgentFullName varchar(150) null,
    CoListAgentLastName varchar(50) null,
    CoListAgentMlsId varchar(25) null,
    CoListOfficeMlsId varchar(25) null,
    CoListOfficeName varchar(255) null,
    ConstructionMaterials text null,
    Cooling text null,
    CoolingYN tinyint(1) null,
    CountyOrParish varchar(50) null,
    CurrentUse text null,
    DirectionFaces varchar(25) null,
    DistanceToPhoneServiceNumeric int null,
    DistanceToPhoneServiceUnits varchar(25) null,
    Electric text null,
    ExteriorFeatures text null,
    Fencing text null,
    FireplaceFeatures text null,
    FireplaceYN tinyint(1) null,
    FireplacesTotal int null,
    Flooring text null,
    FoundationDetails text null,
    GarageSpaces int null,
    GreenBuildingVerificationType text null,
    Heating text null,
    HeatingYN tinyint(1) null,
    InteriorFeatures text null,
    InternetAutomatedValuationDisplayYN tinyint(1) null,
    InternetConsumerCommentYN tinyint(1) null,
    InternetEntireListingDisplayYN tinyint(1) null,
    LaundryFeatures text null,
    Levels text null,
    ListAgentFirstName varchar(50) null,
    ListAgentFullName varchar(150) null,
    ListAgentLastName varchar(50) null,
    ListingKey varchar(255) null,
    ListingKeyNumeric int null,
    LivingAreaUnits varchar(25) null,
    LotFeatures text null,
    LotSizeAcres int null,
    LotSizeArea int null,
    LotSizeDimensions varchar(150) null,
    LotSizeSquareFeet int null,
    LotSizeUnits varchar(25) null,
    MLSAreaMajor varchar(255) null,
    MobileLength int null,
    MobileWidth int null,
    NewConstructionYN tinyint(1) null,
    NumberOfUnitsTotal int null,
    OriginatingSystemKey varchar(255) null,
    OriginatingSystemName varchar(255) null,
    ParcelNumber varchar(50) null,
    ParkName varchar(50) null,
    ParkingFeatures text null,
    PatioAndPorchFeatures text null,
    PhotosChangeTimestamp varchar(27) null,
    PhotosCount int null,
    PoolFeatures text null,
    PoolPrivateYN tinyint(1) null,
    PostalCode varchar(10) null,
    PostalCodePlus4 varchar(4) null,
    PropertyAttachedYN tinyint(1) null,
    PropertySubType varchar(50) null,
    PublicRemarks text null,
    RentIncludes text null,
    Roof text null,
    RoomType text null,
    RoomsTotal int null,
    SeniorCommunityYN tinyint(1) null,
    Sewer text null,
    Skirt text null,
    SpaFeatures text null,
    StateOrProvince varchar(2) null,
    Stories int null,
    StoriesTotal int null,
    SubdivisionName varchar(50) null,
    Topography varchar(255) null,
    UnitTypeType text null,
    UniversalPropertyId varchar(128) null,
    Utilities text null,
    View text null,
    VirtualTourURLUnbranded text null,
    WaterBodyName varchar(50) null,
    WaterSource text null,
    WindowFeatures text null,
    YearBuilt int null,
    Zoning varchar(25) null,
    MemberFirstName varchar(50) null,
    MemberFullName varchar(150) null,
    MemberKey varchar(255) null,
    MemberKeyNumeric int null,
    MemberLastName varchar(50) null,
    MemberMiddleName varchar(50) null,
    MemberNameSuffix varchar(10) null,
    MemberNickname varchar(50) null,
    MemberStateLicense varchar(50) null,
    MemberStateLicenseState varchar(2) null,
    MemberOfficeKey varchar(255) null,
    MemberOfficeKeyNumeric int null,
    MemberOfficeMlsId varchar(25) null,
    MemberOfficeName varchar(255) null,
    MemberOriginatingSystemID varchar(25) null,
    OriginatingSystemMemberKey varchar(255) null,
    SourceSystemMemberKey varchar(255) null,
    IDXOfficeParticipationYN tinyint(1) null,
    MainOfficeKey varchar(255) null,
    MainOfficeKeyNumeric int null,
    MainOfficeMlsId varchar(25) null,
    OfficeAddress1 varchar(50) null,
    OfficeAddress2 varchar(50) null,
    OfficeBrokerKey varchar(255) null,
    OfficeBrokerKeyNumeric int null,
    OfficeCity varchar(50) null,
    OfficeKey varchar(255) null,
    OfficeKeyNumeric int null,
    OfficeMlsId varchar(25) null,
    OfficeName varchar(255) null,
    OfficePhone varchar(16) null,
    OfficePostalCode varchar(10) null,
    OfficePostalCodePlus4 varchar(4) null,
    OfficeStateOrProvince varchar(2) null,
    OfficeOriginatingSystemID varchar(25) null,
    OfficeOriginatingSystemName varchar(255) null,
    OriginatingSystemOfficeKey varchar(255) null,
    SourceSystemID varchar(25) null,
    SourceSystemName varchar(255) null,
    SourceSystemOfficeKey varchar(255) null,
    ImageHeight int null,
    ImageOf varchar(50) null,
    ImageSizeDescription varchar(50) null,
    ImageWidth int null,
    MediaCategory varchar(50) null,
    MediaKey varchar(255) null,
    MediaKeyNumeric int null,
    MediaMediaModificationTimestamp varchar(27) null,
    MediaStatus varchar(50) null,
    MediaURL text null,
    MediaModificationTimestamp varchar(27) null,
    MediaOriginatingSystemID varchar(25) null,
    OriginatingSystemMediaKey varchar(255) null,
    ResourceName varchar(50) null,
    ResourceRecordKey varchar(255) null,
    ResourceRecordKeyNumeric int null,
    MediaSourceSystemID varchar(255) null,
    SourceSystemMediaKey varchar(255) null,
    OpenHouseListingKey varchar(255) null,
    OpenHouseListingKeyNumeric int null,
    OpenHouseDate date null,
    OpenHouseEndTime varchar(27) null,
    OpenHouseKey varchar(255) null,
    OpenHouseKeyNumeric int null,
    OpenHouseRemarks text null,
    OpenHouseStartTime varchar(27) null,
    OpenHouseStatus varchar(25) null,
    OpenHouseType varchar(25) null,
    OriginalEntryTimestamp varchar(27) null,
    OpenHouseOriginatingSystemID varchar(25) null,
    OpenHouseOriginatingSystemKey varchar(255) null,
    Refreshments varchar(255) null,
    ShowingAgentKey varchar(255) null,
    ShowingAgentKeyNumeric int null,
    OpenHouseSourceSystemID varchar(25) null,
    OpenHouseSourceSystemKey varchar(255) null,
    BuyerAgentFirstName varchar(50) null,
    BuyerAgentFullName varchar(150) null,
    BuyerAgentLastName varchar(50) null,
    BuyerAgentMlsId varchar(25) null,
    BuyerOfficeMlsId varchar(25) null,
    BuyerOfficeName varchar(255) null,
    CloseDate date null,
    ClosePrice int null,
    CoBuyerAgentFirstName varchar(50) null,
    CoBuyerAgentFullName varchar(150) null,
    CoBuyerAgentLastName varchar(50) null,
    CoBuyerAgentMlsId varchar(25) null,
    CoBuyerOfficeMlsId varchar(25) null,
    CoBuyerOfficeName varchar(255) null,
    Directions varchar(255) null,
    ElementarySchool varchar(50) null,
    ElementarySchoolDistrict varchar(50) null,
    HighSchool varchar(50) null,
    HighSchoolDistrict varchar(50) null,
    InternetAddressDisplayYN tinyint(1) null,
    LivingArea int null,
    LivingAreaSource varchar(50) null,
    MiddleOrJuniorSchool varchar(50) null,
    MiddleOrJuniorSchoolDistrict varchar(50) null,
    MlsStatus varchar(50) null,
    OnMarketDate date null,
    PossibleUse text null,
    PriceChangeTimestamp varchar(27) null,
    SpecialListingConditions text null,
    StreetDirPrefix varchar(15) null,
    StreetDirSuffix varchar(15) null,
    StreetName varchar(50) null,
    StreetNumber varchar(25) null,
    StreetNumberNumeric int null,
    StreetSuffix varchar(25) null,
    StreetSuffixModifier varchar(25) null,
    TaxAnnualAmount int null,
    UnitNumber varchar(25) null,
    UnparsedAddress varchar(255) null,
    WaterfrontYN tinyint(1) null,
    MemberEmail varchar(80) null,
    MemberLoginId varchar(25) null,
    MemberMlsId varchar(25) null,
    MemberPreferredPhone varchar(16) null,
    MemberPreferredPhoneExt varchar(10) null,
    ListingContractDate date null,
    created_at timestamp null,
    updated_at timestamp null,
    picturesDownloaded tinyint(1) default 0 null,
    PermitAddressInternetYN tinyint(1) null,
    PermitInternetYN tinyint(1) null,
    InternetExposure varchar(50) null,
    uniqueKey varchar(50) null,
    geocoded int default 0 null,
    latitude float(10,6) default 0.000000 null,
    longtitude float(10,6) default 0.000000 null,
    pt point not null,
    ListAgentStateLicense varchar(50) null,
    CoListAgentStateLicense varchar(50) null,
    BuyerAgentStateLicense varchar(50) null,
    CoBuyerAgentStateLicense varchar(50) null,
    constraint properties__Search
        unique (ListPrice desc, ListingId, PropertySubType, MLSAreaMajor,
            StandardStatus, LotSizeSquareFeet desc, BedroomsTotal,
            BathroomsTotalInteger, ListAgentMlsId,
            InternetEntireListingDisplayYN, picturesDownloaded)
)
collate=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

create index properties_AgentMLSID
    on properties (ListAgentMlsId);

create index properties__ListingID
    on properties (ListingId);

create index properties__PostalCode
    on properties (PostalCode);

create spatial index properties__pt
    on properties (pt);
```

Runnung a query on this table goes fast without the spatial aspects. We have around 280000 records. This is only a small version. For another client with the same table, we have 4.000.000 records.

**EDIT 2 :)**

Adding more context. I use MySQL 8.0.20 and have 2 queries running on a search page: https://grantvandyke.com/map/ as an example

This first one is to retrieve the number of results to build up the found listings

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM properties
    WHERE ListPrice >= 300000 AND MBRCONTAINS(ST_MakeEnvelope(Point(33.497224314994114, -111.98568371835003),
           Point(33.43897750924284, -112.09826410537367)), pt)
    AND PicturesDownloaded = 1 AND InternetEntireListingDisplayYN = 1;
```

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | properties | NULL | ALL | properties__Search | NULL | NULL | NULL | 253000 | 0.5 | Using where |

The second query on this page fetches the listings themselves with a limit of 60

```
SELECT
p.City,
p.ListPrice,
p.ListingId,
p.BathroomsFull,
p.BathroomsTotalInteger,
p.BedroomsTotal,
p.LotSizeSquareFeet,
p.LotSizeUnits,
p.PostalCode,
p.StateOrProvince,
p.StreetDirPrefix,
p.StreetDirSuffix,
p.StreetName,
p.StreetNumber,
p.StreetSuffix,
p.StreetSuffixModifier,
p.StandardStatus,
p.latitude,
p.longtitude,
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(storedUrl) FROM images I
    WHERE i.ListingId = p.ListingId) AS imgurl
FROM properties p WHERE p.ListPrice >= 300000
      AND ST_Contains(ST_MakeEnvelope(Point(33.497224314994114, -111.98568371835003),
        Point(33.43897750924284, -112.09826410537367)), p.pt)
      AND p.PicturesDownloaded = 1
      AND p.InternetEntireListingDisplayYN = 1
    ORDER BY p.ListPrice DESC LIMIT 0,60;
```

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | p | NULL | range | properties__Search | properties__Search | 5 | NULL | 126500 | 1 | Using index condition; Using where |
| 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | i | NULL | ref | images__listingID | images__listingID | 1023 | rc-armls.p.ListingId | 27 | 100 | NULL |

My code transforms it to JSON to be used in the page site:

```
0   
TotalResults    "14951"
1   
0   
City    "Scottsdale"
ListPrice   "11000000"
ListingId   "6157504"
BathroomsTotalInteger   "7"
BedroomsTotal   "6"
LotSizeSquareFeet   "1159972"
LotSizeUnits    null
PostalCode  "85266"
StateOrProvince "AZ"
StreetDirPrefix "E"
StreetDirSuffix ""
StreetName  "DIXILETA"
StreetNumber    "8291"
StreetSuffix    "Drive"
StreetSuffixModifier    null
picture "listing-for-sale/6157504/8291-E-E-DIXILETA-Drive-Scottsdale-AZ-85266-1.jpg"
StandardStatus  "Active"
1   
City    "Scottsdale"
ListPrice   "10995000"
ListingId   "6150750"
BathroomsTotalInteger   "8"
BedroomsTotal   "6"
LotSizeSquareFeet   "74867"
LotSizeUnits    null
PostalCode  "85255"
StateOrProvince "AZ"
StreetDirPrefix "E"
StreetDirSuffix ""
StreetName  "SAGUARO CANYON"
StreetNumber    "11007"
StreetSuffix    "Trail"
StreetSuffixModifier    null
picture "listing-for-sale/6150750/11007-E-E-SAGUARO-CANYON-Trail-Scottsdale-AZ-85255-1.jpg"
StandardStatus  "Active"
2   
City    "Scottsdale"
ListPrice   "10850000"
ListingId   "6156863"
BathroomsTotalInteger   "9"
BedroomsTotal   "6"
LotSizeSquareFeet   "44135"
LotSizeUnits    null
PostalCode  "85262"
StateOrProvince "AZ"
StreetDirPrefix "N"
StreetDirSuffix ""
StreetName  "101st"
StreetNumber    "41917"
StreetSuffix    "Place"
StreetSuffixModifier    null
picture "listing-for-sale/6156863/41917-N-N-101st-Place-Scottsdale-AZ-85262-1.jpg"
StandardStatus  "Active"
3   
City    "Scottsdale"
ListPrice   "10500000"
ListingId   "6211048"
BathroomsTotalInteger   "7"
BedroomsTotal   "5"
LotSizeSquareFeet   "130592"
LotSizeUnits    null
PostalCode  "85255"
StateOrProvince "AZ"
StreetDirPrefix "N"
StreetDirSuffix ""
StreetName  "104TH"
StreetNumber    "20981"
StreetSuffix    "Way"
StreetSuffixModifier    null
picture "listing-for-sale/6211048/20981-N-N-104TH-Way-Scottsdale-AZ-85255-1.jpg"
StandardStatus  "Active"
4   
City    "Paradise Valley"
ListPrice   "10000000"
ListingId   "6148731"
BathroomsTotalInteger   "9"
BedroomsTotal   "8"
LotSizeSquareFeet   "155673"
LotSizeUnits    null
PostalCode  "85253"
StateOrProvince "AZ"
StreetDirPrefix "N"
StreetDirSuffix ""
StreetName  "Palo Cristi"
StreetNumber    "5837"
StreetSuffix    "Road"
StreetSuffixModifier    null
picture "listing-for-sale/6148731/5837-N-N-Palo-Cristi-Road-Paradise-Valley-AZ-85253-1.jpg"
StandardStatus  "Active"
5   
City    "Scottsdale"
ListPrice   "10000000"
ListingId   "6201670"
BathroomsTotalInteger   "5"
BedroomsTotal   "3"
LotSizeSquareFeet   "59240"
LotSizeUnits    null
PostalCode  "85262"
StateOrProvince "AZ"
StreetDirPrefix "E"
StreetDirSuffix ""
StreetName  "RELIC ROCK"
StreetNumber    "10016"
StreetSuffix    "Road"
StreetSuffixModifier    null
picture "listing-for-sale/6201670/10016-E-E-RELIC-ROCK-Road-Scottsdale-AZ-85262-1.jpg"
StandardStatus  "Active"
6   
City    "Scottsdale"
ListPrice   "9995000"
ListingId   "5891291"
BathroomsTotalInteger   "6"
BedroomsTotal   "4"
LotSizeSquareFeet   "135531"
LotSizeUnits    null
PostalCode  "85262"
StateOrProvince "AZ"
StreetDirPrefix "E"
StreetDirSuffix ""
StreetName  "Cintarosa"
StreetNumber    "9661"
StreetSuffix    "Pass"
StreetSuffixModifier    null
picture "listing-for-sale/5891291/9661-E-E-Cintarosa-Pass-Scottsdale-AZ-85262-1.jpg"
StandardStatus  "Active"
7   
City    "Scottsdale"
ListPrice   "9750000"
ListingId   "6028659"
BathroomsTotalInteger   "6"
BedroomsTotal   "5"
LotSizeSquareFeet   "100545"
LotSizeUnits    null
PostalCode  "85262"
StateOrProvince "AZ"
StreetDirPrefix "E"
StreetDirSuffix ""
StreetName  "GRAPEVINE PASS"
StreetNumber    "9300"
StreetSuffix    "Road"
StreetSuffixModifier    null
picture "listing-for-sale/6028659/9300-E-E-GRAPEVINE-PASS-Road-Scottsdale-AZ-85262-1.jpg"
StandardStatus  "Pending"
8   
City    "Scottsdale"
ListPrice   "9750000"
ListingId   "6178366"
BathroomsTotalInteger   "8"
BedroomsTotal   "6"
LotSizeSquareFeet   "406939"
LotSizeUnits    null
PostalCode  "85255"
StateOrProvince "AZ"
StreetDirPrefix "E"
StreetDirSuffix ""
StreetName  "RIMROCK"
StreetNumber    "10731"
StreetSuffix    "Drive"
StreetSuffixModifier    null
picture "listing-for-sale/6178366/10731-E-E-RIMROCK-Drive-Scottsdale-AZ-85255-1.jpg"
StandardStatus  "Pending"
9   
City    "Scottsdale"
ListPrice   "9749900"
ListingId   "6023236"
BathroomsTotalInteger   "8"
BedroomsTotal   "5"
LotSizeSquareFeet   "92218"
LotSizeUnits    null
PostalCode  "85255"
StateOrProvince "AZ"
StreetDirPrefix "N"
StreetDirSuffix ""
StreetName  "110TH"
StreetNumber    "21297"
StreetSuffix    "Way"
StreetSuffixModifier    null
picture "listing-for-sale/6023236/21297-N-N-110TH-Way-Scottsdale-AZ-85255-1.jpg"
StandardStatus  "Active"
10  
City    "Scottsdale"
ListPrice   "9500000"
ListingId   "5999488"
BathroomsTotalInteger   "8"
BedroomsTotal   "5"
LotSizeSquareFeet   "60133"
LotSizeUnits    null
PostalCode  "85255"
StateOrProvince "AZ"
StreetDirPrefix "E"
StreetDirSuffix ""
StreetName  "Mountain Spring"
StreetNumber    "10835"
StreetSuffix    "Road"
StreetSuffixModifier    null
picture "listing-for-sale/5999488/10835-E-E-Mountain-Spring-Road-Scottsdale-AZ-85255-1.jpg"
StandardStatus  "Active"
11  
City    "Scottsdale"
ListPrice   "8999000"
ListingId   "6163378"
BathroomsTotalInteger   "8"
BedroomsTotal   "5"
LotSizeSquareFeet   "60133"
LotSizeUnits    null
PostalCode  "85255"
StateOrProvince "AZ"
StreetDirPrefix "E"
StreetDirSuffix ""
StreetName  "Mountain Spring"
StreetNumber    "10835"
StreetSuffix    "Road"
StreetSuffixModifier    null
picture "listing-for-sale/6163378/10835-E-E-Mountain-Spring-Road-Scottsdale-AZ-85255-1.jpg"
StandardStatus  "Active"
12  
City    "Scottsdale"
ListPrice   "8997009"
ListingId   "5918202"
BathroomsTotalInteger   "5"
BedroomsTotal   "4"
LotSizeSquareFeet   "43621"
LotSizeUnits    null
PostalCode  "85262"
StateOrProvince "AZ"
StreetDirPrefix "N"
StreetDirSuffix ""
StreetName  "99TH"
StreetNumber    "41796"
StreetSuffix    "Way"
StreetSuffixModifier    null
picture "listing-for-sale/5918202/41796-N-N-99TH-Way-Scottsdale-AZ-85262-1.jpg"
StandardStatus  "Active"
13  
City    "Phoenix"
ListPrice   "8995000"
ListingId   "6035704"
BathroomsTotalInteger   "14"
BedroomsTotal   "6"
LotSizeSquareFeet   "71343"
LotSizeUnits    null
PostalCode  "85018"
StateOrProvince "AZ"
StreetDirPrefix "N"
StreetDirSuffix ""
StreetName  "ARCADIA"
StreetNumber    "4415"
StreetSuffix    "Lane"
StreetSuffixModifier    null
picture "listing-for-sale/6035704/4415-N-N-ARCADIA-Lane-Phoenix-AZ-85018-1.jpg"
StandardStatus  "Pending"
14  
City    "Phoenix"
ListPrice   "8900000"
ListingId   "6205114"
BathroomsTotalInteger   "7"
BedroomsTotal   "6"
LotSizeSquareFeet   "45868"
LotSizeUnits    null
PostalCode  "85016"
StateOrProvince "AZ"
StreetDirPrefix "E"
StreetDirSuffix ""
StreetName  "BILTMORE"
StreetNumber    "42"
StreetSuffix    "Estate"
StreetSuffixModifier    null
picture "listing-for-sale/6205114/42-E-E-BILTMORE-Estate-Phoenix-AZ-85016-1.jpg"
StandardStatus  "Active"
```

ADDING EXPLAIN

```
    | EXPLAIN |
| :--- |
| {<br/>  "query\_block": {<br/>    "select\_id": 1,<br/>    "cost\_info": {<br/>      "query\_cost": "60947.00"<br/>    },<br/>    "ordering\_operation": {<br/>      "using\_filesort": false,<br/>      "table": {<br/>        "table\_name": "p",<br/>        "access\_type": "range",<br/>        "possible\_keys": \[<br/>          "properties\_\_Search"<br/>        \],<br/>        "key": "properties\_\_Search",<br/>        "used\_key\_parts": \[<br/>          "ListPrice"<br/>        \],<br/>        "key\_length": "5",<br/>        "rows\_examined\_per\_scan": 126500,<br/>        "rows\_produced\_per\_join": 1265,<br/>        "filtered": "1.00",<br/>        "index\_condition": "\(\(\`rc-armls\`.\`p\`.\`InternetEntireListingDisplayYN\` = 1\) and \(\`rc-armls\`.\`p\`.\`picturesDownloaded\` = 1\) and \(\`rc-armls\`.\`p\`.\`ListPrice\` &gt;= 300000\)\)",<br/>        "cost\_info": {<br/>          "read\_cost": "60820.50",<br/>          "eval\_cost": "126.50",<br/>          "prefix\_cost": "60947.00",<br/>          "data\_read\_per\_join": "70M"<br/>        },<br/>        "used\_columns": \[<br/>          "id",<br/>          "City",<br/>          "ListPrice",<br/>          "ListingId",<br/>          "StandardStatus",<br/>          "BathroomsFull",<br/>          "BathroomsTotalInteger",<br/>          "BedroomsTotal",<br/>          "InternetEntireListingDisplayYN",<br/>          "LotSizeSquareFeet",<br/>          "LotSizeUnits",<br/>          "PostalCode",<br/>          "StateOrProvince",<br/>          "StreetDirPrefix",<br/>          "StreetDirSuffix",<br/>          "StreetName",<br/>          "StreetNumber",<br/>          "StreetSuffix",<br/>          "StreetSuffixModifier",<br/>          "picturesDownloaded",<br/>          "latitude",<br/>          "longtitude",<br/>          "pt"<br/>        \],<br/>        "attached\_condition": "st\_contains\(&lt;cache&gt;\(st\_makeenvelope\(point\(33.497224314994114,-\(111.98568371835003\)\),point\(33.43897750924284,-\(112.09826410537367\)\)\)\),\`rc-armls\`.\`p\`.\`pt\`\)"<br/>      },<br/>      "select\_list\_subqueries": \[<br/>        {<br/>          "dependent": true,<br/>          "cacheable": false,<br/>          "query\_block": {<br/>            "select\_id": 2,<br/>            "cost\_info": {<br/>              "query\_cost": "31.66"<br/>            },<br/>            "table": {<br/>              "table\_name": "i",<br/>              "access\_type": "ref",<br/>              "possible\_keys": \[<br/>                "images\_\_listingID"<br/>              \],<br/>              "key": "images\_\_listingID",<br/>              "used\_key\_parts": \[<br/>                "ListingId"<br/>              \],<br/>              "key\_length": "1023",<br/>              "ref": \[<br/>                "rc-armls.p.ListingId"<br/>              \],<br/>              "rows\_examined\_per\_scan": 28,<br/>              "rows\_produced\_per\_join": 28,<br/>              "filtered": "100.00",<br/>              "cost\_info": {<br/>                "read\_cost": "28.78",<br/>                "eval\_cost": "2.88",<br/>                "prefix\_cost": "31.66",<br/>                "data\_read\_per\_join": "35K"<br/>              },<br/>              "used\_columns": \[<br/>                "ListingId",<br/>                "storedUrl"<br/>              \]<br/>            }<br/>          }<br/>        }<br/>      \]<br/>    }<br/>  }<br/>} |
```

Comment: How many rows in the table?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Updated the original post

Comment: Which MySQL version?  Could you provide a tiny (10-row, 2 column) test case that demonstrates the problem.  I am thinking that the specific functions being used may not be optimal.

Comment: Added additional elements to the original post. I have the impression that the count(*) may be the culprit here as I seem to have similar issues with larger result sets on that same site

Comment: What is the definition of images__listingID?  See what happens if you add `FORCE INDEX(properties__pt)`.

Comment: images__listingsID is the index of the images table. It is used to fetch the matching images related a specific listing. This join is only used in fetching the data, we don't use it in the count(*) query.

I did adding the FORCE INDEX on the count query and it takes the query 16 seconds to run. No index was used when doing an explain.

Comment: looks complex :)

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE images__listingID`

Comment: If `COUNT(*)` is the only problem, you may have to avoid doing it.  The complexity of the query makes it difficult to optimize.

Answer (score 0):

If `COUNT(*)` is the only problem, you may have to avoid doing it.  The complexity of the query makes it difficult to optimize.

You could keep the count, but not wait for it with this technique:

1. Display the non-COUNT stuff.
2. Then, use AJAX to do the COUNT.  It will asynchronously come back; when it does, put the count into the suitable spot on the page.

(The user may not even notice that the count is delayed; they will be busy looking at the map and images.)

As for the non-COUNT query, please provide `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`.  This may give a clue of why it is not making better use of the SPATIAL index.

Comment: Interesting suggestion related to the 'COUNT(*)'. I updated the original post with the 'EXPLAIN'

Comment: I did another speed test and it is clearly the row count that is lagging. The search itself is max 3.5s retrieving 60 rows including all images (from the other table). The row count takes more than 10 seconds

Comment: Would moving to Postgres speed up the database?

Comment: @EricC - I don't know enough about Postgres to answer.  For many things, all databases are equivalent -- stuck with going at disk speed.

Comment: https://grantvandyke.com/map updated in this way... first loads the number of results. then doing an ajax request to get the count. It is still slow, and will have an impact on the user experience. but it is a temporary solution.

Comment: @EricC - The page seems a lot faster.  The count is miserably slow.  Might it be better to say "Displaying 1-60", then have the AJAX return tack on " of 495 properties"?